# Unity: Offloading decision making to threads for efficiency?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I've got a fairly large Unity application here that has a lot of concurrent things happening at once. I realized that having all my evaluation, iteration, enumeration, decision making, and arithmetic logic being done in or called from `Update()` is starting to have a performance impact. I've since then offloaded most of this logic to Coroutines, and that has gained back some performance, but I'm trying to think of what I can do to make this better.

Coroutines have gained back performance when iterating over some large collection because I can yield at the end of each loop, but in some cases where it's a massive collection, processing one item each frame makes this task considerably slow. This is where I'm instead starting to offload these sorts of tasks to Threads. Problem with using Threads in Unity is that it tends to throw a fit if you call the Unity API from the Thread. So to combat that, I came up with this design pattern where the non-Unity logic is done in a thread, then once a decision or result was made, some additional Unity-required logic based on context is done in Unity's main thread.

```
public class Evaluator : MonoBehaviour {

   public static Evaluator Instance;

   static Queue<Func<Action>> evaluationQueue = new Queue<Func<Action>>();
   static Queue<Action> actionQueue = new Queue<Action>();
   static Thread evaluatorLoop;

   public static void EvalLogic (Func<Action> evaluation) {
      if (Instance == null) {
         NanoDebug.LogError("EVALUATOR IS NOT INITIALIZED!");
         return;
      }

      evaluationQueue.Enqueue(evaluation);

      if (evaluatorLoop == null) {
         evaluatorLoop = new Thread(EvaluatorLoop);
         evaluatorLoop.IsBackground = true;
         evaluatorLoop.Start();
      }
   }

   static void EvaluatorLoop () {
      for (;;) {
         if (evaluationQueue.Count > 0) {
            Func<Action> evaluation = evaluationQueue.Dequeue();
            Action action = evaluation();
            actionQueue.Enqueue(action);
         }
         else {
            break;
         }
      }
      evaluatorLoop = null;
   }

   void Awake () {
      Instance = this;
   }

   void FixedUpdate () {
      if (actionQueue.Count > 0) {
         actionQueue.Dequeue()?.Invoke();
      }
   }
}
```

In some regular script, I would use this like so

```
void OnSomeGameEvent (GameEventBigData bigData) {
   Func<Action> checkData = () => {
      // Iterate over some big collection.
      // Do X if some condition is met during iteration.
      // Do some arithmetic with data.
      // Evaluate some large if-statement or switch statement.

      // Return this Action based on the decision or result of the above.
      return () => {
         // Mutate the state of some object involving the Unity API using evaluated data.
      };
   };
   Evaluator.EvalLogic(checkData);
}
```

I've ran into a simular problem with large iterations using this pattern. While the Thread does the iteration also instantly, if I need to mutate the state of a collection of Game Objects (each one), then the above action queue fills up to the size of the collection and then it's up to the speed of `FixedUpdate()` to apply the selected changes. But, when it comes to complex decision making or doing math, this pattern seems to help Unity not skip a beat.

So my question is: Am I really gaining performace this way, or am I better off sticking to just Coroutines and intelligently yielding when necessary?

Here's my understanding of what `Update()` is. It's a render loop, right? If you want to chagne the state of a Game Object in such a way that it changes the visual appearance or location, you do it `Update()`. That being said, doesn't it make more sense to then offload *ALL* non-render related tasks from `Update()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: **Depends on your specific use case.**

> Am I really gaining performace this way, or am I better off sticking to just Coroutines and intelligently yielding when necessary?

That totally depends on what actually is done by the threads / Coroutine and how many of them you are using etc.

Using threads for performance instense things (mostly FileIO, parsing operations on large or many `string`s or in general large data processing) wherever you can definitely is a performance gain. However, have in mind that also creating threads has a certain overload. If you are to create them on a regular basis it is even better to have one persistent thread and then pass in work packages it has to solve. While there are no packages it should then sleep for a certain amount of time (e.g. 17ms which is about a frame in 60 FpS or even longer - I e.g. usually used 50ms and for now was quite happy with the results) so it doesn't eat up 100% of CPU time while it has nothing to do.

> It's a render loop, right?

Not really, no. `Update` is just a message that gets invoked once each frame. What you do in there is of course up to you. As yourself said most of the Unity API (namely these parts that directly affect the scene or assets or rely on them) can only be used within the Unity main thread, so any of Unity's built-in messages (`Update`, `FixedUpdate`, etc).

> That being said, doesn't it make more sense to then offload ALL non-render related tasks from `Update()`?

No! That would be overdoing it a little. Heavy things, yes why not. **But** have in mind that your device only has a limited amount of parallel CPU cores to work off all the `Thread`s and `Task`s. At a certain point the overhead just grows bigger than the actual work that is done. I wouldn't move each and any `Vector3` calculation into a thread / workPackage .. but if you have to do 1000 of them, again, sur why not.

So as said basically it all comes down to: **Depends on your specific use case.**

---

Alternatively to `Thread`s depending on your needs you might also want to look into the [Unity Job System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html) and the [Burst Compiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.burst@0.2/manual/index.html) which enables to do a lot of things asynchronous that are usually somehow bound to the Unity main thread.

In particular it is used a lot in combination with the new [Mesh API](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/MeshApiExamples).

---

And yet another alternative for heavy but generic mathematical operations would be using [Compute Shaders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ComputeShader.html) so handing all the work to the GPU. This stuff can get extremly complex but at the same time extremly fast and powerfull. (Again see the examples and times in the [MeshAPI examples](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/MeshApiExamples))

---

And in general yes, this kind of dispatching actions/results back into the main thread is the typical solution. Just make sure to either [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) your `actionQueue` or rater use a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1) to not get into threading issues.

Additionally you can have a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) for working the packages off that skips to the next frame if too much time has passed already so you can still achieve a certain target framerate. You could achieve this e.g. using a [`StopWatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch). This requires of course to implement certain points where it may skip (`yield`) like for example after each worked package / `Action`.

```
const float targetFrameRate = 60;

// yes, if you make Start return IEnumerator then Unity automatically
// runs it as a Coroutine
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    // -> about 17 -> actual frame-rate might be only 58 or lower
    var maxMS = Mathf.RoundToInt(1000f / targetFrameRate);

    var stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
 
    // This is ok in a Coroutine as long as you yield inside
    // in order to at least render one frame eventually
    while(true)
    {
        if (actionQueue.Count > 0) 
        {
            actionQueue.Dequeue()?.Invoke();

            // after each invoked action check if the time has already passed
            if(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= targetFrameRate)
            {
                // render this frame and continue int he next
                yield return null;
                // and restart the timer
                stopWatch.Restart();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise directly go to the next frame
            yield return null;
            // and restart the timer
            stopWatch.Restart();
        }
    }
}
```

If this still is not enough and your `Action` itself is too intensive you could split it up in multiple `Action`s in order to again allow to skip between them. Like e.g. instead of doing

```
Enqueue(LoopThroughObjectsAndDoStuff(thousendObjects));
```

you would rather do

```
foreach(var x in thousendObjects) 
{
    Enqueue(()=>DoStuffForObject(x)); 
}
```

---

Have in mind though that there is tradeoff and you have to play around a bit with the target frame-rate and the real-time until everythign is done.

There are situations where you prefer that a User has to wait effectively longer until something is finished but meanwhile have the application run with a good frame-rate. And there are other situations where you allow that the app runs with a lower frame-rate or even little freezes but the process is finished effectively faster.